# How to expose a SOAP data service with a JSON proxy service on ESB?

Tags: json, soap, proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working on Stratos Live.
I have implemented a SOAP data service.
I would like to expose it as a JSON REST service defining a proxy on the ESB.
How can I define it ?
A pass-through proxy ? a transformer-proxy ?
(I have already tried to define a pass-through proxy, but with it I expose soap too; I did not find how to configure json protocol)

I found this example :

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Sample+440%3A+Exposing+a+SOAP+Service+Over+JSON

But it refers to an on premise use : how can I use it on Stratos Live console ?
Is there an example for Stratos Live too ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your data as RESTful resources directly from the WSO2 Data Services Server. Following documentation will help you on it.
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/Expose+Data+as+REST+Resources

You don't need an ESB proxy service in this situation because your requirement can be achieved directly from the Data Services Server. A proxy service might become handy if you had any transformation or service chaining kind of scenarios to be done.

Comment: I read the example in the link and implemented a restful service on the data server. But I cannot see a JSON transformation. The response is still in XML format. How and where (ESB proxy ? data server ?) can I transform it in JSON format ?

Comment: Of course it would be better to have the *JSON* response generated at the data service layer (I would like to let the ESB just proxying). Is it possible ? If not possible to generate the JSON response at the data service layer, I think I should do it at the ESB layer, with the proxy. But in this case we are back at my original question .....